# mongoose syntax with user.id connecting to a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Hi I am new to mongoose and with angular through ionic. I am trying to build an app and having problem with it. I have no Idea if this syntax mongoose is right because it still is not working in my front end where the user picks and answer and it saves it to the database

Heres my mongoose question.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Question = require('../models/Question.js');
var app = express();




 // GET questions listing. questions/yourroute
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
 Question.find(function(err, questions){
 if(err) return next(err);

 res.json(questions);

 });
 });

 router.post('/saved-questions', function(req, res){

 var now = Date()
 User.findById(user.id, function(err, user){

var newanswer1 = {
    question: '58ccb991caf9756f8e1d8a6c',
    answer_text: req.body.Q1,
    postdate: now
 }



 });


 user.users_answers.push(newanswer1);

 //repeat for Q 2 and 3, push each time

 User.save()

  });
  module.exports = router;
```

And this is the form in ionic.. I don't know why its not working, maybe its how im putting it in the ionic form. There suppose to be slides of questions in ionic and each possible answer is in the ion check box

```
 <div id="questions" ng-controller="QCntrl">

 <ion-content>
 <ion-slide-box>
 <ion-slide>
 <div class="intro" ng-controller="PopupCtrl">
    <h1 class="hidden">Intro Question</h1>
    <h3>Just need to ask some questions to make this app personalized for you</h3>
    <button class="button" value="next" ng-click="nextSlide()">OKAY</button>
     <button class="button2 button-positive" ng-click="PopAlert()">
  Why?
     </button>

   </div>

  </ion-slide>




  <ion-slide>
  <div id="Q1box">
  <h2>{{questions[0].question_text}}</h2>
 <ul>
 <li data-ng-repeat="answer in answers1">
 <ion-checkbox id="Q1" ng-model="filter.users_answers">{{answer.label}}</ion-    checkbox>
</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" ng-click="next()">Next Question</a>
</div>
</ion-slide>
```

Comment: I don't really get what are your trying to do or what is not working. But if it is something with mongoose, you could try adding a callback to Users.save() to catch and log the error if there is any: Users.save(function(err) { console.log(err) });

Comment: This is very difficult to read or reason about due to the lack of proper indentation. If you have something like a syntax error it's helpful to actually post the error. Beautifying your code leads to this: https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/638c51db5b804348353a661ab519022d with the obvious error.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `User.save()`, try changing it to `user.save` and move the `})` that's before `User.save` and put it after where you change `User.save` to `user.save`

You are editing the user you just found with  `User.findById(user.id, function(err, user){`
  and it seems you then want to save the push you made to `user.users_answers` which `user.save` should do for you